# Opencart Create new options for leasing

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

recently, I installed Opencart cms for my business in order to sell and rent some products. At first everything was okay, I designed a logo, creating a beautiful theme and putting a new category. but after a time, I found that I can not rent a product without editing the source code of Opencart, and I found a difficult to do that.
I tried to edit `/catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php` by adding an `if-else` statment for **$product_data[]** on line 239 and replacing the plus sign with multiplication sign for 'price' and 'total' to become like that:

from:

```
 $product_data[] = array(
                    'cart_id'         => $cart['cart_id'],
                    'product_id'      => $product_query->row['product_id'],
                    'name'            => $product_query->row['name'],
                    'model'           => $product_query->row['model'],
                    'shipping'        => $product_query->row['shipping'],
                    'image'           => $product_query->row['image'],
                    'option'          => $option_data,
                    'download'        => $download_data,
                    'quantity'        => $cart['quantity'],
                    'minimum'         => $product_query->row['minimum'],
                    'subtract'        => $product_query->row['subtract'],
                    'stock'           => $stock,
                    'price'           => ($price + $option_price),
                    'total'           => ($price + $option_price) * $cart['quantity'],
                    'reward'          => $reward * $cart['quantity'],
                    'points'          => ($product_query->row['points'] ? ($product_query->row['points'] + $option_points) * $cart['quantity'] : 0),
                    'tax_class_id'    => $product_query->row['tax_class_id'],
                    'weight'          => ($product_query->row['weight'] + $option_weight) * $cart['quantity'],
                    'weight_class_id' => $product_query->row['weight_class_id'],
                    'length'          => $product_query->row['length'],
                    'width'           => $product_query->row['width'],
                    'height'          => $product_query->row['height'],
                    'length_class_id' => $product_query->row['length_class_id'],
                    'recurring'       => $recurring
                );
```

to:

```
if $option_query->row['type'] == 'select' & $option_query->row['name'] == 'Duration')
{
$product_data[] = array(
                'cart_id'         => $cart['cart_id'],
                'product_id'      => $product_query->row['product_id'],
                'name'            => $product_query->row['name'],
                'model'           => $product_query->row['model'],
                'shipping'        => $product_query->row['shipping'],
                'image'           => $product_query->row['image'],
                'option'          => $option_data,
                'download'        => $download_data,
                'quantity'        => $cart['quantity'],
                'minimum'         => $product_query->row['minimum'],
                'subtract'        => $product_query->row['subtract'],
                'stock'           => $stock,
                'price'           => ($price * $option_price),
                'total'           => ($price * $option_price) * $cart['quantity'],
                'reward'          => $reward * $cart['quantity'],
                'points'          => ($product_query->row['points'] ? ($product_query->row['points'] + $option_points) * $cart['quantity'] : 0),
                'tax_class_id'    => $product_query->row['tax_class_id'],
                'weight'          => ($product_query->row['weight'] + $option_weight) * $cart['quantity'],
                'weight_class_id' => $product_query->row['weight_class_id'],
                'length'          => $product_query->row['length'],
                'width'           => $product_query->row['width'],
                'height'          => $product_query->row['height'],
                'length_class_id' => $product_query->row['length_class_id'],
                'recurring'       => $recurring
            );
}else{
$product_data[] = array(
                'cart_id'         => $cart['cart_id'],
                'product_id'      => $product_query->row['product_id'],
                'name'            => $product_query->row['name'],
                'model'           => $product_query->row['model'],
                'shipping'        => $product_query->row['shipping'],
                'image'           => $product_query->row['image'],
                'option'          => $option_data,
                'download'        => $download_data,
                'quantity'        => $cart['quantity'],
                'minimum'         => $product_query->row['minimum'],
                'subtract'        => $product_query->row['subtract'],
                'stock'           => $stock,
                'price'           => ($price + $option_price),
                'total'           => ($price + $option_price) * $cart['quantity'],
                'reward'          => $reward * $cart['quantity'],
                'points'          => ($product_query->row['points'] ? ($product_query->row['points'] + $option_points) * $cart['quantity'] : 0),
                'tax_class_id'    => $product_query->row['tax_class_id'],
                'weight'          => ($product_query->row['weight'] + $option_weight) * $cart['quantity'],
                'weight_class_id' => $product_query->row['weight_class_id'],
                'length'          => $product_query->row['length'],
                'width'           => $product_query->row['width'],
                'height'          => $product_query->row['height'],
                'length_class_id' => $product_query->row['length_class_id'],
                'recurring'       => $recurring
            );                              
}
```

but when i try to test it, when i put on the same card a **Duration** option with another different option I get a large sum ($price * $option_price) for all card items

please how can I fix it or are there another method to rent and sale product in the same time on Opencart

**Simplification:**
I want to add a Duration option price (1 day or 2 days...) which customer can choose how many days he will rent the product and return it.
total = item price * duration(number of day) * quantity of product

Comment: Why did you replace plus with star , you just add that amount as option price

Comment: thank you,I want to add a Duration option price (1 day or 2 days...) which customer can choose how many days he will rent the product and return it.
total = item price * duration(number of day) * quantity of product